# Tried to scrape a webpage by using BeautifulSoup4 and then it just stops halfway through

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am a noob to Python BeautifulSoup, in fact I am noob to Python at all. I tried to scrape this webpage (https://th.jbl.com/bluetooth-portables) as a self-study exercise. I would like to scrape the SKU information of each product: category, subcategory, name, and productID to be precise.  I managed to scrape category, subcategory, and most of the product name as well as their productID, but as you may see the product listings in this page is not consistent, and I just got repeatedly stuck to product: Xtreme 2 which does not have productID.  At this stage, the scrape just flatly stops, whilst there are still 3 product tiles in need of scraping.

I tried and tried but just couldn't get through. As a matter of fact, Xtreme 2 is only get printed with name, but no information is written to the file.

My method is to scrape all tiles that contains products whilst ignore the rest. Below are the codes:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests, csv, codecs, json

    jbl_file = codecs.open('JBL_TH.csv','w',encoding='utf_8_sig')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(jbl_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Category','Subcategory','Product','Prod_ID'])

    url = 'https://th.jbl.com/bluetooth-portables'
    source = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    home = soup.find('div',class_='breadcrumb clearfix')

    # find the category and subcategory
    category = home.find('h2',property='name').text
    subcategory = home.find('span',class_='breadcrumb-last',property='name').text


    # define the scope of product container
    all = soup.find('div',id='search-result-items')
    # each product is in a tile, so find all the tiles
    for tile in all.find_all('div',class_='product-tile'):
        print(category)
        print(subcategory)

        # the tile may not contain product, hence steps to ignore such tile by try ... except ...
        try:
            # find out the name of the product in each tile
            name = tile.find('a',class_='productname-link')['title']
            print(name)

            # even if product exists in the tile, SKU ID may not exist in class product-swtches,
            # hence set to ignore by try ... except ...
            try:
                # SKU ID is in the product-swatches class
                directory = tile.find('div',class_='product-swatches')
                # each product may contain multiple SKU ID, each in one sawtch-data,
                # hence using another for loop
                for colour in directory.find_all('div', class_='swatch-data'):
                    product_id = json.loads(colour.text)['productID']
                    print(product_id)
                    # set to write the found category, subcategory, name, and product_id to the csv file
                    csv_writer.writerow([category,subcategory,name,product_id])
            except:
                name = 'dummy'
                product_id = 'dummy'
                print(name)
                print(product_id)
                # if do not find them, use dummy as name and product_id
                csv_writer.writerow([category,subcategory,name,product_id])

        except:
            name = 'dummy'
            product_id = 'dummy'
            print(name)
            print(product_id)
            # if do not find them, use dummy as name an
            csv_writer.writerow([category,subcategory,name,product_id])

    jbl_file.close()
```

I also attach two screenshots details what information I am trying to scrape. Can someone kindly help me through this?

[image: category and subcategory of the products]
[image: product name and productID]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is the entire page. This page only contains a few products, and loads more products using javascript when you scroll down the page in a browser.

Since BeautifulSoup doesn't execute javascript, you have to either use a different tool that does (like Selenium) or try to mimic what the javascript does yourself.

By using the developer network inspector in a browser (press the F12 key in firefox) I can see that after scrolling down, the browser emits a request to the url `https://th.jbl.com/bluetooth-portables?prefn1=isAvailabilityforLocale&prefn2=isRefurbished&prefv3=false&sz=12&start=12&format=page-element&prefv1=yes&prefv2=false&prefn3=isSupport`.

As you can see it uses the `start=12` parameter to define that it wants results starting from position 12 - it seems you can manipulate that parameter to get the data you want.

```
n = 0
while True:
    n = n + 12
    new_url = 'https://th.jbl.com/bluetooth-portables?sz=12&start={}'.format(n)
    # fetch new_url and repeat parsing...
```

Comment: I tried and it is still not working.  The product seems get printed, but they weren't written to the csv file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `getattr`:

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://th.jbl.com/bluetooth-portables').text, 'html.parser')
category = d.find('h2', {'property':'name'}).text
subcategory = d.find('span', {'class':'breadcrumb-last'}).text
products = [i for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':'product-tile'})]
headers = [['a', {'class':'productname-link'}], ['div', {'class':'swatch-data'}]]
new_products = [[getattr(i, 'find', lambda *_:None)(*b) for b in headers] for i in products]
final_products = [[getattr(a, 'attrs', lambda x:{'title':None}[x]).get('title'), json.loads(getattr(b, 'text', '{}')).get('productID')] for a, b in new_products]
```

Output:

```
Wireless
Portables
[['JBL Flip 4', 'JBLFLIP4BLKAM'], [None, None], ['JBL Flip 3', 'JBLFLIP3BLK'], ['JBL Flip 3 Special Edition', 'JBLFLIP3MALTA'], ['JBL Charge 3', 'JBLCHARGE3BLKAS'], ['JBL Charge 3 Special Edition', 'JBLCHARGE3MOSAICAS'], ['JBL Clip 2', 'JBLCLIP2BLK'], ['JBL Clip 2 Special Edition', 'JBLCLIP2MALTA'], ['JBL Pulse 2', 'JBLPULSE2BLKAS'], ['JBL GO', 'JBLGOBLK'], ['JBL Xtreme', 'JBLXTREMEBLKAS'], ['JBL Xtreme Special Edition', 'JBLXTREMESQUADAS'], ['Xtreme 2', None]]
```

---

To write to a `csv` file, you can use this:

```
import csv
with open('product_listings.csv', 'w') as f:
  write = csv.writer(f)
  write.writerows([['category', 'subcategory', 'title', 'id'], [category, subcategory]+(['']*2)]+[(['']*2)+['' if not i else i for i in b] for b in final_products if any(b)])
```

Output:

```
category,subcategory,title,id
Wireless,Portables,,
,,JBL Flip 4,JBLFLIP4BLKAM
,,JBL Flip 3,JBLFLIP3BLK
,,JBL Flip 3 Special Edition,JBLFLIP3MALTA
,,JBL Charge 3,JBLCHARGE3BLKAS
,,JBL Charge 3 Special Edition,JBLCHARGE3MOSAICAS
,,JBL Clip 2,JBLCLIP2BLK
,,JBL Clip 2 Special Edition,JBLCLIP2MALTA
,,JBL Pulse 2,JBLPULSE2BLKAS
,,JBL GO,JBLGOBLK
,,JBL Xtreme,JBLXTREMEBLKAS
,,JBL Xtreme Special Edition,JBLXTREMESQUADAS
,,Xtreme 2,
```

---

Edit: using `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/driver')
d.get('https://th.jbl.com/bluetooth-portables')
last_height = d.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
  d.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
  time.sleep(1)
  new_height = d.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
  if new_height == last_height:
    break
  last_height = new_height

_d = soup(d.page_source, 'lxml')
category = _d.find('h2', {'property':'name'}).text
subcategory = _d.find('span', {'class':'breadcrumb-last'}).text
products = [i for i in _d.find_all('div', {'class':'product-tile'})]
headers = [['a', {'class':'productname-link'}], ['div', {'class':'swatch-data'}]]
new_products = [[getattr(i, 'find', lambda *_:None)(*b) for b in headers] for i in products]
final_products = [[getattr(a, 'attrs', lambda x:{'title':None}[x]).get('title'), json.loads(getattr(b, 'text', '{}')).get('productID')] for a, b in new_products]
```

Output:

```
[['JBL Flip 4', u'JBLFLIP4BLKAM'], [None, None], ['JBL Flip 3', u'JBLFLIP3BLK'], ['JBL Flip 3 Special Edition', u'JBLFLIP3MALTA'], ['JBL Charge 3', u'JBLCHARGE3BLKAS'], ['JBL Charge 3 Special Edition', u'JBLCHARGE3MOSAICAS'], ['JBL Clip 2', u'JBLCLIP2BLK'], ['JBL Clip 2 Special Edition', u'JBLCLIP2MALTA'], ['JBL Pulse 2', u'JBLPULSE2BLKAS'], ['JBL GO', u'JBLGOBLK'], ['JBL Xtreme', u'JBLXTREMEBLKAS'], ['JBL Xtreme Special Edition', u'JBLXTREMESQUADAS'], ['Xtreme 2', None], ['CLIP 3', u'JBLCLIP3BLK'], [None, None], ['JBL GO 2', u'JBLGO2BLK'], ['Pulse 3', u'JBLPULSE3BLKJN']]
```

Comment: I need the product ID, not the colour name.

Comment: @lukayl You explicitly state in your question, in the screenshot details, that "each colour indicates one productId". Can you clarify how the output above is not your desired result?

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain very clear.  If you inspect any colour element, you can find a <div class="swatch-data">, under this div class, there is a json file {}, in it, there is a list for "productID":"JBLFLIP4BLKAM".  This is the one I am trying to scrape. Thank you.

Comment: @lukayl My apologies, I see what you mean. Please see my recent edit, as I fixed this, and also provided a way to write the data to a `csv` file.

Comment: I tried your code, but it isn't working.  It still stops at Xtreme 2.

Comment: @lukayl Can you clarify what you mean by "stops"? Is an error raised?

Comment: If you open the url link https://th.jbl.com/bluetooth-portables and scroll down manually, you may find Xtreme 2 is not the last product, there are three more, also each product usually has more than one productID, but the code only scrapes ony productID per product, and then it moves to the next product.

Comment: It really doesn't work. I think you didn't import BeautifulSoup. I tried to import it and tried to add codes to accommodate what you input, but I have traceback.

Comment: You still there?